# How /Where to call init() method when deploying web service using Axis 1.4?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, init, axis

I am using Axis 1.4 in Tomcat 6 to deploy my web service. I have a class like this:

```
class helloService{
  ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>
  /*Some declarations*/
  public void init(){
     helloService hs= new helloService();
     //File reads,variable initialization and all the init processes
  }

  public void add(int x, int y)
  { return x+y; }
  public void subtract(int x,int y)
  {return x-y;  }
}
```

I want to provide `add()` and `subtract()` for clients, but to work those two method(Please consider there exists some operations rather than adding and subtracting, this is a sample) it is needed to call `init()` method first.

How to call `init()` method when deploying web service since because there's no server class to call the `init()` method unlike in RPC/RMI?

Comment: Can't you put in a default constructor that calls init?

Comment: Seems like there's no reason to call `new hellowService()` from an object of type `helloService` that already exists. Did you mean to make that method `static`?